# How can I script Perforce to merge non-conflict code?

Tags: merge, perforce

### Background

- We have scripts that generate a large portion of our code.
- We don't want to use scripts for generating all of the code.
- Typically, we would keep this code separate, but we are considering scripts that generate portions of the code that will also be modified by programmers, e.g. function / class definitions,  i.e. first we parse a header file that specifies the function parameters and enumerations, then we generate all the empty functions.
- We can ensure that programmers will never modify code that is generated by the scripts.
- We need a method to automate the merging of these files after being edited by the scripts;  e.g. our input definition file is updated (externally) and we need to modify the function parameters.

### Method

Two scripts: "Previous" and "Current" (identical)

1. Modify "Current" and regenerate code; "P4 edit" into changelist
2. Merge code:

   2.a. Base = Generated code from "Previous"; in temporary folder

   2.b. Left = Generated code from "Current"

   2.c. Right = Existing code; current version checked into P4
3. Save "Current" as "Previous"

### Problem

I can't figure out how to automate step #2.  We have over 100 files we'd like to auto generate so manually merging is not an option.

Using "p4merge.exe" requires GUI interaction; as far as I can tell.

I looked at "p4 merge", "p4 integrate", "p4 resolve" and "p4 sync", but I couldn't figure out how to invoke the correct behavior.

Any help would be appreciated, including alternative methods.

Cheers.

Comment: `p4 sync && p4 resolve -am`?

Comment: I need to explicitly set the base version, and have the merge completed without user input

Comment: Then couldn't you do `p4 sync @CLN` to sync to a particular base changeset, apply the external changes, and then do sync + resolve to automatically merge? `p4 resolve -am` will resolve everything it can without user input.  However, you haven't explained what's supposed to happen if conflicts occur.

Comment: Can @CLN be a Pending Changelist? Remember that when I rerun the script, the code generated will appear to remove all the user code, and automatic merges will commit that. I need to specify that the base version is some other version than what has ever been checked in to perforce.

Comment: I can ensure that no conflicts will occur.

Answer (score 1):

Per jamesdlin's comments, I figured out how to accomplish what I wanted.

### New Method

One script "Current".

Add generated files to P4 (always version #1)

1. "p4 sync [file]#1" then "p4 edit [file]"
2. Modify "Current" and regenerate code
3. Run "p4 sync" again (without revisions) to mark the files for resolve.
4. Run "p4 resolve -am" to auto resolve the files.

This should work even after multiple iterations of the script.  As long as I can avoid conflicts then this should be completely automated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than combining your machine-generated code in the same source files as the human-authored code, what about changing your code generation strategy so that your tool generates the super-class code, and humans can individually author sub-classes of the machine-generated classes which override the necessary methods to provide the needed behavior.

That's how I've typically done this sort of development in the past.

Comment: I generally agree. We were considering how we could use perforce to merge the files to get around adding more infrastructure, such as includes for user code. p.s. - this is for a low-level, near real time library, this the need to generate hundreds of functions. While we are using templates to minimize user code, we are not allowed to use polymorphism due to performance issues. Thanks for your advice though.